# Modal shows text of first modal instead of second one

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I have a code where the modal opens a popup when you click on a button. At the 2nd button you are supposed to get the 2nd modal to be opened, but it keeps showing the text of the first modal. I do have the right id. How can I fix this? (//2 is for the second button)

It tells me to add more details to this question, but that's all I need to know. This is the code for it.

```
if ($_SESSION['type'] == 1)
{
    ?>

    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="myBtn">Klassen aanmaken</button>
        <button id="myBtn2">Studenten aanmaken</button>
        <button id="myBtn3">Docenten aanmaken</button>
        <button id="myBtn4">Klassen bijwerken</button>
        <button id="myBtn5">Studenten bijwerken</button>
        <button id="myBtn6">Docenten verwijderen</button>
        <a href="logout.php">Uitloggen</a>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

<!-- The 2nd Modal -->
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>
    </body>

    <script>
//1
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//2
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal2");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//3
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn3");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//4
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn4");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//5
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn5");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

//6
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn6");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
    <?php
}
else if ($_SESSION['type'] == 2)
{
    ?>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
    body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

    /* The Modal (background) */
    .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
    }

    /* Modal Content */
    .modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%;
    }

    /* The Close Button */
    .close {
    color: #aaaaaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="myBtn">Klassen bekijken</button>
        <button id="myBtn2">Studenten bekijken</button>
        <a href="logout.php">Uitloggen</a>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Some text in the Modal..</p>
  </div>

</div>

    </body>

    <script>

        //1
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        }

            //2
        // Get the modal
        var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

        // Get the button that opens the modal
        var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn2");

        // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
        var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

        // When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
        btn.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "block";
        }

        // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
        span.onclick = function() {
        modal.style.display = "none";
        }

        // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (event.target == modal) {
            modal.style.display = "none";
        }
        }
    </script>
    <?php
    
}
else
{
    header('Location: login.html');
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Every time you assign to `window.onclick` you're replacing the previous one.

Comment: You're using the same global variable `modal` in all the `onclick` functions. When you click on them, the variable contains the last modal that you assigned to the variable.

Comment: You can use `addEventListener()` to put multiple click listeners on `window`. You can use IIFEs to define all the other click handlers in a scope with a different binding of `modal`.